# ¿Cómo detectar la dirección(izquierda,derecha,arriba,abajo) al mover el dedo por la pantalla (no las coordenadas)?

Tags: android, eventos

Hola pues vengo a buscar ayuda con ustedes Programadores ya que no tiene mucho que empeze en android studio y pues veran quiero saber como puedo hacer una app que al deslizar el dedo en la pantalla digamos hacia la derecha en un `textview` me diga "deslizaste derecha ".

El problema es que no se como registrar, No el `touch` si no la direccion.

Hasta ahora lo unico que pude hacer es que me diga si pulse la pantalla, si solte la pantalla, me estoy moviendo y que coordenadas tiene el lugar en el que estoy tocando.

¿Me podrian ayudar o decirme que puedo buscar? me siento perdido

Comment: Si obtienes las coordenadas de inicio y fin, puedes calcular si te encuentras a la derecha, izquierda, arriba, abajo o alguna diagonal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, para detectar el `swipe` con las 4 direcciones básicas (up,down,left,right) puedes utilizar la siguiente clase

**OnSwipeTouchListener.java**

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                } 
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

**Su uso:**
Para usarlo, se debe asignar al objeto donde quieres detectar el `swipe`

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MyActivity.this) {
    public void onSwipeTop() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeBottom() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
```

Solución extraída de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)
También puedes ojear la documentación en Google dev [(Detecting Common Gestures)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/gestures/detector.html), que amplia la información de como detectar otras pulsaciones `tap, doble tap`...

Otro método es usar la librería swipe, detecta mientras se hace swiping y swipe  https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3323

Comment: Muchas Gracias! me Ayudo muchisimo tu respuesta! 
Gracias por ayudarme a seguir con mi proyecto! 
Saludos!

Comment: @JohnCorfishCastle Me alegra que haya sido de ayuda, entre todos nos ayudamos es lo bueno de esta comunidad, no olvides en marcarla como resuelta

Answer (score 3):

Yo lo veo mucho más fácil:
Tienes que saber que se llama al evento onTouch cada vez que hay un evento en la pantalla.
Te pongo un ejemplo a código:

```
public class Ejemplo implements View.OnTouchListener{
    private int firstTouchX;
    private int firstTouchY;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(...){
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Aqui guardas en una variable privada de clase las coordenadas del primer toque:
                firstTouchX = event.getX();
                firstTouchY = event.getY(); 
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //Aqui ya podemos determinar los tipos de movimientos:
                if(fistTouchX > event.getX()){
                    //Hacia la izquierda
                }else{
                    //Hacia la derecha
                }
                if(fistTouchY > event.getY()){
                    //Hacia arriba
                }else{
                    //Hacia abajo
                }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Espero haber solucionado tu duda.

Editado:
He añadido el **return true** al método onTouch. Esto es importante para el **ACTION_MOVE** sino, no funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro me ayudo a orientarme tu respuesta!

Comment: Nada tio! Un placer haber ayudado!